# Появление ползунка не влияет на положение страницы

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Приветствую всех жителей ХэшКода! Как настроение?

Ребята, задумался над такой идеей, которую реализовали Вконтакте.Всем знакома ситуация большого объёма контента, когда он вылазит за границы монитора вниз по вертикали появляется всем известный ползунок с правой стороны.Так вот, если у страницы стоит позиционирование по центру, то она автоматом смещается на ширину ползунка в лево.

Вопрос: как реализовать фиксированное положение страницы по центру, даже при появление ползунка при большом объёме информации, т.е чтобы при появление ползунка страница не смещалась в право на его ширину, а оставалась на своём месте.

Пример: [вконтакте, раздел для веб-разработ.](http://vk.com/developers.php#devstep2) Пощёлкайте по табам, обратите внимание на ползунок и на фикс.положение сайта.Нужно так же сделать.Идеи?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Идея взята отттуда-же:
Контент сайта (div#pageLayout) отцентрован с помощью margin:0 auto; Это делает одинаковые поля слева и справа. Сам этот контент вложен в ещё один (div#pageContainer), ширина которого равна текущей window.innerWidth (у меня при развёрнутом окне 1439px)(она автоматически перерассчитывается onResize функцией ниже)

```
onBodyResize() = function () {
    var dwidth = Math.max(intval(window.innerWidth), intval(document.documentElement.offsetWidth));
    if (window.lastWindowWidth != dwidth) {
        window.lastWindowWidth = dwidth;
        if (browser.msie6) {
            return;
        }
        var pl = ge("pageLayout").offsetWidth, sbw = sbWidth();
        if (document.body.offsetWidth < pl) {
            document.body.style.overflowX = "auto";
            dwidth = pl + sbw + 2;
        } else {
            document.body.style.overflowX = "hidden";
        }
        if (dwidth) {
            ge("pageContainer").style.width = dwidth - sbw - 2 + "px";
        }
    }
}

ge = getElementById
```

sbWidth() меряет ширину ползунка и кэширует это значение

Так-же при этом соответствующим образом проставляется overflow-x