# Точное выравнивание блока по центру без влияния скролла

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, решил исправить в дизайне небольшой дефект. Имеется сайт, который располагается фиксировано по центру страницы. При появлении полоски скроллбара сайт сдвигатся влево. В ВКонтакте этого не происходит.
Как убрать этот дефект? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Появление ползунка не влияет на положение страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/79543/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

Answer (score 0):

Страница VK уже изначально идет со сдвигом влево, поскольку полоса прокрутки присутствует всегда, за исключением страницы авторизации!